# How to migrate models when I django test with parallel option?

Tags: python, django

When I tried to test with parrallel option(--parallel=3), all models migrated in only one database. (I expected that models migrated in all databases. How can I fix it?

I tried to run:

```
python manage.py test --settings=server.settings.test --parallel=3
```

I got Error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'test_xxx_1.company' doesn't exist")
```

Comment: Did you ever got an answer for that ?